# Use Variable in Command Option’s Value

Tags: laravel

I want to use a variable for the default value of an option in a command. I also want a related variable in the signature, but I get the following error.

> Expression is not allowed as field default value

**Signature**

```php
protected $signature = "app:FixStepsStatistics {phone?*}{--dateFrom=$this->dateFrom}{--dateTo=}";

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->dateFrom = Carbon::now();
}
```

Can I use a variable in my signature?

Comment: You get the error on `$this->dateFrom = Carbon::now();`?

Comment: @Tarasovych no . in signature property i get this error

Comment: So the error tells you all about that. No expressions. You're trying to assign something is not a string.

Comment: if i set a string in construct . i get this error again . what is solution?@Tarasovych

Comment: How do you set it in construct? Show your code

Comment: @Tarasovych     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->dateFrom = '123';
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187680/discussion-between-sinak-and-tarasovych).

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare class variables with constant values, can't do it using other variables.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

This will fail:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $thing1 = 'hello';
    protected $thing2 = $this->thing1.' world';   // invalid in PHP
}
```

Instead, you could set the default value to an empty string, and then assign a default if needed in the `handle()` method.

```
protected $signature = "app:FixStepsStatistics {phone?*}{--dateFrom=}{--dateTo=}";

public function handle()
{
    $dateFrom = $this->option('dateFrom');

    $dateFrom = $dateFrom ?
                Carbon::parse($dateFrom) :
                Carbon::now();
}
```